# Python Concatenating Strings

Tags: python

```
  1 def add(i):
  2     return '\''+i+'\''
  3 a = ['a', 'b']
  4 print " or ".join([add(i) for i in a])
```

OUTPUT: `'a' or 'b'`

I am not sure if the above is the best way (esp the add function).
Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Make your Question more Clear

Comment: @wcdolphin ['a', 'b'] to print 'a' or 'b'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b']
>>> print " or ".join(repr(i) for i in a)
'a' or 'b'
```